# bitwise c - inside a for loop different result (don't know how to put is better)

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

```
int bitcheck(int test){
    int result = 0, unit = 0, i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        unit = test >> i & 1;
        result |= unit << (8 - i - 1) + result;
    }
    return result;
    }
```

let's say test = 77 (0100 1101)

when i = 2, unit will be equal 1 and result will be (before "result |=..") equals 128. so how come 1 << 133 (before the calculation "result | outcome") is 0010 0000? (I printed every step), but if I do 1<<133 by it self the outcome is 0000 0000?

I know why the outcome of 1<<133 is 0000 0000, but why is it different in the for loop?

```
test is: 01001101

unit when i is 0: 00000001
00000001<<00000111 = 10000000
result when i is 0: 10000000

unit when i is 1: 00000000
00000000<<10000110 = 00000000
result when i is 1: 10000000

unit when i is 2: 00000001
00000001<<10000101 = 00100000
result when i is 2: 10100000

unit when i is 3: 00000001
00000001<<10100100 = 00010000
result when i is 3: 10110000

unit when i is 4: 00000000
00000000<<10110011 = 00000000
result when i is 4: 10110000

unit when i is 5: 00000000
00000000<<10110010 = 00000000
result when i is 5: 10110000

unit when i is 6: 00000001
00000001<<10110001 = 00000000
result when i is 6: 10110000

unit when i is 7: 00000000
00000000<<10110000 = 00000000
result when i is 7: 10110000


return result: 10110000
```

Comment: Please state what you want to accomplish: input, desired output.

Comment: So you're shifting 32-bit (`int` is usually 32 bits even on 64 bit platforms) value by 133 bits? Stop and think about that for a while. Then read about [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: This question suppose to be basic, like pre programming curse level, I don't think it involve "high level" stuff

Comment: @Oriel Cochavi: What exactly is the intended purpose of `result |= unit << (8 - i - 1) + result;` expression? Why are you adding the `resut` and OR-ing it at the same time? What were you trying to achieve by this? In other words, why are you trying to shift a 8-bit value by hundreds(!) of bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the others have noted, this is [undefined behavior](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213), which means that if the C standard is all you have to go by, in theory anything could happen.

I think that's a somewhat unhelpful answer to your question though, as you're left wondering why the same operation on the same two numbers gives different results. After all, while the C standard doesn't specify what the result will be, the CPU itself does follow its own specification of how bitwise shift instructions should work, and that's unlikely to involve generating random results.

The differences you are seeing is most likely due to the difference between the CPU's implementation of bitshifts and the implementation the compiler uses when precomputing results that are known at compile time. Consider for example this simple example:

```
$ cat shift.c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  uint32_t a = atoi(argv[1]), b = atoi(argv[2]), c, d;
  c = a << b;
  d = 1u << 133u;
  printf("%08x << %08x = %08x\n",a,b,c);
  printf("%08x << %08x = %08x\n",1,133,d);
  return 0;
}
$ gcc -o shift{,.c}
shift.c: In function ‘main’:
shift.c:9:2: warning: left shift count >= width of type
$ ./shift 1 133
00000001 << 00000085 = 00000020
00000001 << 00000085 = 00000000
```

This was run on an Intel Core2 Duo cpu. What seems like the same operation is done twice here with different results. But those two operations are not actually equivalent. The first one involves numbers the compiler does not know the value of, so they are simply compiled into a `sall` x86 instruction. This instruction [only uses the lowest 5 bits of the count](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html). The lowest 5 bits of 133 (0x85) is 5, so the bitshift actually performed is 1 << 5 = 32 (0x20), which matchers the output. So that makes sense.

But what's happening with the other line? Here the compiler knows what the two operands are, so it can just precompute the result and store it. No `sall` instruction is produced. gcc's implementation of bitshifts (which only comes into play when the result can be computed at compile time) handles too large counts differently than `sall`. In this case the whole count is effectively used, and all the bits are shifted away.

So to summarize:

1. The illegal count results in undefined behavior
2. An undefined shift of values that are known at compile time exposes the compiler's implementation of the undefined operation.
3. An undefined shift of values that are *not* known at compile time exposes the CPU's implementation of the undefined operation.
4. Point 2 and 3 are the reason why you see inconsistent results for your bitshift.

Answer (score 0):

A [negative shift count or one larger than or equal to the bitsize of the left argument](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.7p3) results in [*undefined behaviour*](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3p1).

So, you can not expect the result to be 0, but be aware of [demons flying out of your nose](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html).

Also, right shifting a signed integer with negative value is *implementation defined*. IOW, it is left to your compiler/toolchain what happens.

Comment: why 00000001<<10000101 = 00100000 in the loop and when I put the same values out of the loop, the result is 00000000?

Comment: @OrielCochavi: Read about [_undefined behaviour_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behaviour)! It is called like that for a good reason! Once you encounter it, there is littel practial sense in further research in the effect. First remove its cause.

Comment: maybe I didn't understand the "undefined behaviour" correctly, but in this case, the C operator precedence are vary clear, so It does specify the behavior.. shouldn't it print 00000001<<10000101 = 00000000 or am I missing something? as I said before, this question is vary basic, so it shouldn't involve  "undefined behaviour" and such.

Comment: @Oriel Cochavi: "... I put the same values out of the loop ..." - what does this mean? Where and how do you "put the same values out of the loop"? I don't see it in your code. Can you provide an example?

Comment: @OrielCochavi: _Operator precedence_ does not specify the **behaviour** of an operator, but the **order** operations in an expression are performed. The _behaviour_ of an operation is defined by the _operator_. This includes the valid input range of each operand and the result. For values outside the valid range, the standard defines for bitshift operators that there is no defined behaviour of the program anymore => _undefined behaviour_.

Answer (score 0):

```
shift-expression << additive-expression
```

The result of a shift operation is *undefined* if `additive-expression` is negative or if `additive-expression` is greater than or equal to the number of bits in the (promoted) `shift-expression`.

```
unsigned int int1 = 4;
unsigned int int2 = int1 << -3;  // C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
unsigned int int4 = int1 << 32;  // C4293: '<<' : shift count negative or too big, undefined behavior
```

The above example is taken from [VS 2013, section: Additional Details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx). Although the example code is written in C++ but it is same in C too.

> so how come 1 << 133 (before the calculation "result | outcome") is 0010 0000?

It is `0010 0000` instead of `0000 0000` because of [Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). May be next time you will get another value. You just can not defined an *Undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 0):

after adding parens to get the desired sequence of operations

Note: when desiring a fix for a runtime problem, post executable code.

I think the source of the problem is

```
1) using undefined behaviour due to the 'too large' shift amounts
2) ignoring the precedence of operators in C
```

Here is the code I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int test = 0x4d;
    int result = 0;
    int unit = 0;
    int i;

    printf( "test=%d\n", test );
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        unit = (test >> i) & 1;
        printf( "unit=%d\n", unit);
        result |= (unit << (8 - i - 1)) + result;
        printf( "i=%d, result=%x\n", i, result );
    }
    return result;
}
```

and here is the result:

```
test=77
unit=1
i=0, result=80
unit=0
i=1, result=80
unit=1
i=2, result=a0
unit=1
i=3, result=b0
unit=0
i=4, result=b0
unit=0
i=5, result=b0
unit=1
i=6, result=b2
unit=0
i=7, result=b2


------------------
(program exited with code: 178)
```

Answer (score -1):

From your result:

```
         00000001<<00000111 gets you 10000000, 
which should be 1<<00000111
         00000001<<10000101 gets you 00100000, 
which should be 1<<00000101
         00000001<<10100100 gets you 00010000, 
which should be 1<<00000100
         00000001<<10110001 gets you 00000000, 
which could be  1<<00010001
```

Do I detect a pattern here?

Comment: There is nothing gained finding a pattern in UB. It will not become more reliable.